# PHP Recursive Array Intersect Key Tripping over string value

Tags: php, oop, recursion, array-intersect

I'm currently receiving an error `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to NUI::recArrInterKey() must be an array, string given` when trying to recursively intersect a multidimensional array (grey/white list).

It seems to be tripping on the `$foo['contact']['im']['provider']` section for some reason that I can't figure out?

Here's an example whitelist array ($array2) that I am using

```
Array
(
    [location] => false
    [network_name] => false
    [interests] => false
    [last_name] => false
    [url] => false
    [significant_other] => false
    [network_domains] => false
    [contact] => Array
        (
            [im] => Array
                (
                    [provider] => false
                )

            [email_addresses] => false
        )

)
```

And the method

```
/**
 * Recursive array intersect key
 */
private static function recArrInterKey(array $array1, array $array2) 
{
    $array1 = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);
    foreach ($array1 as $key => &$value) 
    {
        if (is_array($value)) 
        {
            $value = self::recArrInterKey($value, $array2[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array1;
}
```

lets say that this is `$array1`

```
Array
(
    [location] => Seattle
    [occupation] => Developer
    [network_name] => foo.network
    [network_region] => foo.region
    [interests] => coding
    [last_name] => daniel
    [url] => false
    [id] => 4665228
    [significant_other] => some girl
    [network_domains] => false
    [contact] => Array
        (
            [im] => Array
                (
                    [provider] => aol
                )
            [phone] => Array
                (
                    [provider] => at&t
                )

            [email_addresses] => dont@mail.me
        )

)
```

I am expecting this as a return

```
Array
(
    [location] => Seattle
    [occupation] => Developer
    [network_name] => foo.network
    [interests] => coding
    [last_name] => daniel
    [url] => false
    [significant_other] => some girl
    [network_domains] => false
    [contact] => Array
        (
            [im] => Array
                (
                    [provider] => aol
                )
            [email_addresses] => dont@mail.me
        )

)
```

Comment: check its an array first

Comment: well - you dont check the second parameter: `$array2[$key]` - this also should be an array

Comment: @Adidi Please post that as an answer so I can accept it =) that was the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well - you dont check the second parameter: `$array2[$key]` - this also should be an array

Comment: Cheers, thanks for pointing that out. Its usually the small stuff =/

Answer (score 5):

Because you are using `array_intersect_key`, it only compare keys => `$array1[$key]` might have a value as array but not necessary `$array2[$key]`

You case is a one direction intersect: `recArrInterKey($a1, $a2)` is not the same as `recArrInterKey($a2, $a1)`

Try this fix:

```
private static function recArrInterKey(array $array1, array $array2) 
{
    $array1 = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);
    foreach ($array1 as $key => &$value) 
    {
        if (is_array($value)) 
        {
            $value = is_array($array2[$key]) ? self::recArrInterKey($value, $array2[$key]) : $value;
        }
    }
    return $array1;
}
```